# jcombobox setSelectedItem

Tags: java, swing

I have a created a combo box with three items. I am trying to set the selected item by index and value.

1. When I do setSelectedIndex ()  the code works well.
2. I am trying to set the selected item by value. So I try creating another object, with same value(variable name d), and do setSelectedItem but it fails. When I try printing out the selectedItem, it doesn't print 'C C'. It prints the previously selected item 'B B'

So how do set selectedItem by value? Do advice. 
Thanks so much!

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class testt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        obj a = new obj("A A");
        obj b = new obj("B B");
        obj c = new obj("C C");

        obj[] lst = { a, b, c };

        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(lst);
        box.setSelectedIndex(1);
        System.out.println("value is:"+((obj) box.getSelectedItem()).toString());

        obj d = new obj("C C");
        box.setSelectedItem(d);
        System.out.println(value is:"+((((obj) box.getSelectedItem()).toString());
    }
}

class obj {
    String value;    
    public obj(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }    
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equals and Hashcode issue. The below should solve the problem.

```
  class obj {
    String value;    
    public obj(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }    
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.value);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final obj other = (obj) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.value, other.value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Solution works well. Just some questions.  1. Why did you use 5 and 17 in your hash code? Can we use any number or certain number pairs need to be used?                2. what if the class obj had to many values ? We compare them all too?

Comment: it was a IDE generated hashcode method. Of course you can use any certain pairs. _what if the class obj had to many values ?_ Certain property would define the uniqueness of the object. you can decide based on your design of the object which all properties are going to be unique based on that you can compare.